# Overwriting Browser GeoLocation Notification

Tags: javascript, css, html, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I am getting ready to work with the HTML5 GeoLocation API and I would like to know if it is currently possible to overwrite/style the default browser notification for accepting GeoLocation?

The biggest issue is lack of control over the messaging and how to control what we are telling users about our intent with using their GeoLocation.

It seems pointless to pop-up something on top of the current acceptance options to give the user more detail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to customize these messages. All of the notifications are completely different from user agent to user agent.

Could you not pop up a message before you call navigator.geolocation to give you users more information. That way at least you wouldn't have both messages on screen at once. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thebeebs/bTWhd/1/

Comment: Not a bad idea at all. That's for the concept.

Answer (score 1):

No these are part of the native browser and are intentionally un-editable for security and privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There's going to be no standard way of doing this for all browsers.  It would be probably be best to do this with a tooltip if you don't want the user to have to click through multiple messages.

Comment: Tooltips have been our initial thought, but we'd really like to have a consistant message across all browsers. This may limit our ability to use such a useful function.

Comment: tooltips are a way to have a consistent message across all browsers

Comment: Not mobile ones, if the trigger is 'hover' at least.